# problem with array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, void

I have a problem with my program. I am trying to run trough an array of pointers. Once the right pointer is found the program will print all the pointers that have been visited. I get error message at:

```
void * temp=debut[k]; 
ajouter(temp[k], resultat);
```

it says "void value not ignored as it ought to be"

I don't uderstand why???

thank you in advance for help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int calculerTaille(void * pointeur);
void ajouter(void * pointeur, char * resultat[]);
int verifier(void * debut, void * fin);

void * A[3];
void * D[3];
void * F[2];
void * G[4];
void * H[4];
void * J[3];
void * K[5];
void * L[4];
void * M[5];

int i = 0;

char * resultat[100];

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

A[0] = D;
A[1] = H;
A[2] = K;

D[0] = A;
D[1] = G;
D[2] = H;

F[0] = K;
F[1] = L;

G[0] = D;
G[1] = H;
G[2] = J;
G[3] = M;

H[0] = A;
H[1] = G;
H[2] = L;
H[3] = M;

J[0] = G;
J[1] = L;
J[2] = M;

K[0] = A;
K[1] = F;
K[2] = H;
K[3] = L;
K[4] = M;

L[0] = F;
L[1] = J;
L[2] = K;
L[3] = M;

M[0] = G;
M[1] = H;
M[2] = J;
M[3] = K;
M[4] = L;

void * debut = A;
void * fin = J;


ajouter(J, resultat);
while (verifier(debut, fin) != 1) {

    srand(time(0));
    int k = rand() % calculerTaille(K);

    void * temp=debut[k]; //error
    ajouter(temp[k], resultat); //error

}

int l=0;
for(l=0; resultat[l]!=NULL;l++) printf("%s ", resultat[l]);
return 0;
}

void ajouter(void * pointeur, char * resultat[]) {

if (pointeur == A)
    resultat[i] = "A";
if (pointeur == D)
    resultat[i] = "D";
if (pointeur == F)
    resultat[i] = "F";
if (pointeur == G)
    resultat[i] = "G";
if (pointeur == H)
    resultat[i] = "H";
if (pointeur == J)
    resultat[i] = "J";
if (pointeur == K)
    resultat[i] = "K";
if (pointeur == L)
    resultat[i] = "L";
if (pointeur == M)
    resultat[i] = "M";

i++;

}

int verifier(void * debut, void * fin) {
if (debut == fin)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}

int calculerTaille(void * pointeur) {
if (pointeur == A)
    return 3;
if (pointeur == D)
    return 3;
if (pointeur == F)
    return 2;
if (pointeur == G)
    return 4;
if (pointeur == H)
    return 4;
if (pointeur == J)
    return 3;
if (pointeur == K)
    return 5;
if (pointeur == L)
    return 4;
if (pointeur == M)
    return 5;

}
```

Comment: The structure of your program is very complicated, with lots of `if` statements, et cetera. If one of my students were to write this sort of code, I would ignore their question and ask them to clean up the code or better express their idea. Often times this solves the problem without any further work.

Comment: If you are learning to write code, the question is often not whether or not the code is functional, but whether the code is "beautiful" - a clearly expressed idea is often easy to code, and nice code is often the product of a clearly expressed idea.

Comment: You should include the line number that the error occurs on and also come up with a much simpler example to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`debut` is a pointer of type `void *`. You can't use the `[]` operator with a pointer of type `void *`. It is illegal in C. What is that supposed to mean in your code?

You compiler, obviously, allows you to use the `[]` with `debut` as a compiler-specific extension (this is nevertheless illegal in C). However, the result of `debut[k]` is an "lvalue" of type `void`. You can't read a `void`. You can't assign a `void` to anything. That just doesn't make any sense. What were you trying to say by attempting to read the "value" of `debut[k]`?

---

Taking into account your comment, apparently what you need is `debut` declared as

```
void **debut;
```

Note *two* asterisks.

Again, if you want to access elements of the array `void * A[3]` through an independent pointer `debut`, the pointer `debut` has to be declared and initialized as follows

```
void **debut = A;
```

That way accessing `debut[k]` will actually access `A[k]`.

The same applies to `fin`. In fact, your program contains numerous independent instances of this error (see function parameters as well), although some of them are more "forgiving" than `debut[k]`.

P.S. Your cycle will loop infinitely, since you never change neither `debut` nor `fin`.

Comment: I would like debut to take successive values of pointers (it changes during the program execution)

Answer (score 3):

`temp` and `debut` are void pointers - since `void` has no defined size, the array indexing operator cannot be used on pointers of that type (how big is the object that a `void*` points to?).

Answer (score 1):

`debut` is a void pointer and void pointers cannot be dereferenced without being cast to another pointer type. The array subscript operator `[]` effectively dereferences the base pointer by adding an offset.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `void*` in arithmetic ... so basically when you say `debut[k]`, that requires an addition operation on the pointer value, which you can't do ... you are going to have to cast that pointer value to another pointer type before you can do addition on it.

To be honest, the type of `debut` should actually be `void**` since it's pointing to the array `A` which is an array of pointers to pointers.  You can index into that.  So change your declaration to the following:

```
void ** debut = A;
```

Now it can actually add to `debut`, since it knows that the value it's pointing to is a pointer, and therefore can be incremented by the size of a pointer on your platform.  You still won't be able to make a call like `temp[k]` though, since now `temp` is a `void*` type, but at least `debut[k]` will be valid.

It might be best in the end to actually make your arrays of type `long`, or whatever the size of a pointer on your platform is ... you can then do pointer arithmetic on those types and properly offset into the arrays.  The values will be the same since the stored values are merely addresses which are integral values ... it doesn't look like you're actually doing much deferencing, only equalty checks, so that could work.  Otherwise you will need to make casts to `long` or whatever the size of a pointer on your platform is so you can properly do the indexing necessary to offset into your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can index into a void* since how would the compiler know who many bytes to jump (i.e. index).  You may need to cast first then index.